# Easier way to solve $1-\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{7^2}-\frac1{8^2}-\frac1{10^2}\ldots=\frac49s$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Show that $1-\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{7^2}-\frac1{8^2}-\frac1{10^2}++--\ldots=\frac49s$, where $s=\sum k^{-2}$

I can divide the LHS in the sum of four series

$$1-\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{5^2}+\frac1{7^2}-\frac1{8^2}-\frac1{10^2}++--\ldots=\\=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{(6k-1)^2}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{(6k-5)^2}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{(6k-2)^2}-\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{(6k-4)^2}=\frac49\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{k^2}$$

but manipulating the above expression is so tedious to show the equality. Do you know a different way to solve this problem? Thank you.

P.S.: I dont know exactly what kind of tags use for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't  know if it is an easy way. But I say it anyway.

To make the required sum, we may start from

$S=\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$

Then, we wanna take all the terms of form $\frac{1}{(3k)^2}$ off.

Then, take $2$ times the terms of the form $\frac{1}{(2k)^2}$ off.

As there is an intersection between the terms of the form $\frac{1}{(3k)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(2k)^2}$, $2$ times the terms of the form $\frac{1}{(6k)^2}$ is added.

The final result is

$\sum\frac{1}{k^2}-\sum\frac{1}{(3k)^2}-2\sum\frac{1}{(2k)^2}+2\sum\frac{1}{(6k)^2}=S-\frac{1}{9}S-\frac{1}{2}S+\frac{1}{18}S=\frac{4}{9}S$

Comment: Yes, this is the easier way to do, thank you. Just seeing the elements that are not present in the LHS we can solve this without any other kind of technique or knowledge. I didnt see that there is a relation between parity and sign.

Comment: @Masacroso, I am glad you find it useful

Answer (score 3):

Since $(1,-1,0,-1,1,0)=(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)-(0,0,1,0,0,-1)$ we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} S&=&\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(6k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(6k+2)^2}-\frac{1}{(6k+4)^2}+\frac{1}{(6k+5)^2}\right)\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(3n)^2}\\&=&\frac{8}{9}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}-2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
hence $S=\frac{4}{9}\zeta(2)=\color{red}{\large\frac{2\pi^2}{27}}$ as wanted.

Comment: @Masacroso: here I am just exploiting the fact that we want to compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^2}$ where $\chi(n)$ is an arithmetic function with period $6$. By chance, such function can be written as the difference between an arithmetic function with period $2$ and an arithmetic function with period $6$ associated with the patterns $(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)$ and $(0,0,1,0,0,-1)$. Since $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(hn)^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2h^2},$$ the original series equals $\frac{4}{9}\zeta(2)$.

Comment: @Masacroso: as I said, the series we want to compute is $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^2}$ where the values of $\chi(n)$ over $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ are given by $(1,-1,0,1,-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with [Euler products,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) you can see that

$$1+{1\over5^2}+{1\over7^2}+{1\over11^2}+\cdots=\prod_{p\not=2,3}\left(1-{1\over p^2}\right)^{-1}=\left(1-{1\over 2^2}\right)\left(1-{1\over 3^2}\right)\prod_p\left(1-{1\over p^2}\right)^{-1}\\={3\over4}\cdot{8\over9}\left(1+{1\over2^2}+{1\over3^3}+{1\over4^2}+\cdots\right)={2\over3}s$$

and

$${1\over2^2}+{1\over4^2}+{1\over8^2}+{1\over10^2}+\cdots={1\over2^2}\left(1+{1\over2^2}+{1\over4^2}+{1\over5^2}+\cdots\right)={1\over4}\prod_{p\not=3}\left(1-{1\over p^2}\right)^{-1}={1\over4}\left(1-{1\over 3^2}\right)\prod_p\left(1-{1\over p^2}\right)^{-1}={1\over4}\cdot{8\over9}\left(1+{1\over2^2}+{1\over3^3}+{1\over4^2}+\cdots\right)={2\over9}s$$

It follows that

$$1-{1\over2^2}-{1\over4^2}+{1\over5^2}+{1\over7^2}-{1\over8^2}-{1\over10^2}++--\cdots={2\over3}s-{2\over9}s={4\over9}s$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{\mu} \equiv
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{6k - \mu}^{2}}\,;\qquad
> \mrm{f}\pars{1} - \mrm{f}\pars{2} - \mrm{f}\pars{4} + \mrm{f}\pars{5}:\ ?}$.

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{\mu} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{6k - \mu}^{2}} =
{1 \over 36}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + 1 - \mu/6}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 36}\,\Psi\, '\pars{1 - {\mu \over 6}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\pars{\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mrm{f}\pars{1} - \mrm{f}\pars{2} - \mrm{f}\pars{4} + \mrm{f}\pars{5} =
{1 \over 36}\bracks{\Psi\, '\pars{5 \over 6} - \Psi\, '\pars{2 \over 3} -
\Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 3} + \Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 6}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 36}\braces{\bracks{\Psi\, '\pars{5 \over 6} + \Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 6}} -
\bracks{\Psi\, '\pars{2 \over 3} + \Psi\, '\pars{1 \over 3}}}
\end{align}

---

With the *Euler Reflection Formula*:
\begin{align}
&\mrm{f}\pars{1} - \mrm{f}\pars{2} - \mrm{f}\pars{4} + \mrm{f}\pars{5} =
{1 \over 36}\bracks{\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi \over 6} -
\pi^{2}\csc^{2}\pars{\pi \over 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{{2 \over 27}\,\pi^{2}}} =
{4 \over 9}\pars{\pi^{2} \over 6} =
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{{4 \over 9}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}}} 
\end{align}